# Start terminal when VNC starts and execute a command within the new display

Tags: x11, vnc

How can I start a Terminal within the new Display, and execute a command in that Terminal soon after VNC's startup automatically?

Comment: What VNC server are you using?

Comment: TightVNC @EricRenouf

Comment: You can use `~/.vnc/xstartup` to specify commands to run, you can probably use that to do this